# Working with MiKTeX and WinEdt together

Tags: editors, winedt

How can I work by using WinEdt? Before that I just knew MiKTeX 2.8 and worked with TeXmaker and type with easily, but for some formula my friend introduced me to WinEdt and I don't know the relationship between those. How to I make a PDF with WinEdt? I'd like to learn working with both of them.

Comment: i used WinEdt until 7.1 version but i didn't like. From there i use **TexStudio** and i like because the new features as auto-completed function and others.

Answer (score 1):

There is a toolbar, as in all editors, that allows you to perform most usual tasks for a TeX document. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

As an example, in the centre, you have these 4 icons:

[image]

The second one from the launches `pdflatex` on the current/main file; on its right side, the small black triangle lets you open a dropdown menu that lets you change the compiler. The trash icon is for deleting auxiliary files; it also has a dropdown menu that lets you choose *which* files to delete. The third and four icons launch `biber` and `bibtex` respectively.

Similarly, there are icons for `dvips`, `dvipdfm`, `pstopdf` and , rightmost, for `gsview/ghostscript` and the pdfviewer (default is `sumatrapdf`).